# Bootstrap datetimepicker display current date and allow to pick past dates

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm actually having some issue trying to display the current day and allowing pick past dates. If I set the current date as today's date, I can't pick past dates and if I remove the parameter `startDate: new Date()` I can pick past dates but the default displayed date change to year 1899. I can't keep both logic.

With the following code snippet I can display the current date by default but I can not pick past dates:

```
             $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
                 format: "mm/dd/yyyy HH:ii P",
                 autoclose: true,
                 showMeridian: true,
                 startDate: new Date(),
                 todayBtn: true,
                 minuteStep: 5,
                 language: 'en',
                 forceParse: false
             });
```

So like I said, if I remove the parameter startDate, I can pick past dates but my default displayed date goes to 1899 instead of current date:

```
             $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
                 format: "mm/dd/yyyy HH:ii P",
                 autoclose: true,
                 showMeridian: true,
                 //startDate: new Date(),
                 todayBtn: true,
                 minuteStep: 5,
                 language: 'en',
                 forceParse: false
             });
```

How can I keep both things: pick past dates and show current date by default?
I also tried adding a new function like this but it's not working neither:

```
             $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
                 format: "mm/dd/yyyy HH:ii P",
                 autoclose: true,
                 showMeridian: true,
                 //startDate: new Date(),
                 todayBtn: true,
                 minuteStep: 5,
                 language: 'en',
                 forceParse: false
             }).on('dp.show', function () {
                 return $(this).data('DateTimePicker').defaultDate(new Date());
             });
```

Comment: have you tried with `initialDate: new Date(),`? it is default current date, but who knows, maybe something changed...

Comment: Try `defaultViewDate` options. Docs: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#defaultviewdate

Answer (score 0):

To meet your requirements, you can use `defaultViewDate` and `endDate` options. See the official docs to understand how both works: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html. 
Here is a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/CTrANXLLgaLwT8pIPQV2?p=preview

Comment: Thank you @NiK648 I finally opted for using another bootstrap datetimepicker version a litter bet updated and improved. I previously was using this one: [https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php](DateTimePicker) so I changed to [https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/8jpmkcr5/1/](ImprovedDatetimePicker)  in addition I was also needing display the time So I'm also using moment.js

Answer (score 0):

The answer below is related to bootstrap-datetimepicket from S. Malot, but it might also apply to other versions like the jquery-bootstrap.

!! Since the solution requires changing the source code, do it carefully and test your app again to make sure it doesn't bring unwanted side effects. Everything is OK on my side.

I was looking for the solution for many months and finally fond it in [github Malot](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/207#issuecomment-332190021). Thanks to abcbaby.

I updated ***line 1620*** of the bootstrap-datetimepicker.js with what he/she recommended:

change this

```
date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), // which is Dec. 31, 1899
```

to this

```
date = new Date(), // which is today's date
```

To put things back into their context, I'm using the French regional (`regional: 'fr',`) and language (`language: 'fr',`) and need to show the current date at page opening (date without time) in the "Start Date" field of the member's file. To do this, I use PHP `echo` function with `date ("d F Y")` inside the HTML code.

Everything works fine as long as the date is entered via the widget, but for that field that receives a value outside of the widget, as soon as you click on the field, the date gets reset to 31 December 1899.

With this code hack I don't have this issue anymore.